# Calculating geometry for a polyline of a given thickness

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given points, **p1, p2, p3, p4 ... pn** representing a polyline; how do I calculate the geometry (specially vertices - for drawing in graphics applications) assuming a given thickness **d**. (As in the diagram below)

[image]

Specifically need to find **a, b**, and **c**. 
Note that **line p1 a** is perpendicular to **line p1 p2**.
**Line p2 b** is not perpendicular to **line p1 p2** and also not to **line p2 p3**.

**b** is the intersection of the **line b c** and **line a b** which are parallel to **line p2 p3** and **line p1 p2** respectively.

**d'** is not important, but may prove useful.

Also since all points are represented on the screen as 2 tuples - **(x, y)**; it would be helpful to know **a**, **b** and **c** in the 2 tuple form.

I am thoroughly blanking on how to do this. Any pointers at all will be helpful.

Comment: Try http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @lhf Doesn't matter what I'm going to use it for. This is still a pure mathematics problem.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226569/Drawing-polylines-by-tessellation.

Comment: True, but you're more likely to find good answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the 2D vector $\vec P_{12}$ from $P_1$ to $P_2$. You normalize it to unit length by dividing by its components by its length

$$L_{12}=\sqrt{(P_{2x}-P_{1x})^2+(P_{2y}-P_{1y})^2}$$ and get $\vec p_{12}=(p_{12x},p_{12y})$.

The vector $\vec n_{12}=(-p_{12y},p_{12x})$ is perpendicular to it and also has unit length.

Then $$a=P_1+d\,\vec n_{12}.$$ Similarly, $$c=P_3+d\,\vec n_{23}.$$

$b$ is a little harder. It lies on the bissectrix of $P_{12}$ and $P_{23}$, with a direction vector obtained by the sum $\vec n_{12}+\vec n_{23}$, which you need to normalize to get $\vec n_{123}$.

The distance $d'$ is the same as $d$ with a correction factor obtained by trigonometry from the dot product of $\vec n_{12}$ and $\vec n_{123}$.

Then,

$$b=P_2+d\frac{\vec n_{123}}{\vec n_{12}\cdot \vec n_{123}}.$$

Comment: So elegant! Thank you. I am not sure I understand the calculation of b entirely though. So... what exactly does n12 + n23 mean? Normally, adding vectors would lead to the vector from the base of the first one to head of the other one. Why would n123 (Which I assume is the normal vector in the direction of p2 b) be a sum of n12 and n23? Finally, is n12 dot n123, d'? or its the factor like you mention so d' = d * (n12 dot n123). Think I'll understand b if I understand d' and n123.

Comment: The sum of two vectors of equal length has the direction of their bissectrix. Beware that $n_{123}$ must be normalized to unit length. The formula for $b$ must be taken as is, with $d$ (not $d'$).

Comment: That clears it up nicely. Thanks.

Comment: One last thing: Just so that I'm clear, that means d' = d / n12 dot n123; so d' can also be d / n23 dot n123. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep it is correct. (I hope I made it right :)

Comment: Update: I successfully implemented this in my code. It works flawlessly.